# Floating UIButton over UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton`, which is fixed in position, over a `UICollectionView`, not part of the actual `UICollectionView` view hierarchy.

Is there a way I am able to, on vertical scroll of the `UICollectionView`, to dynamically adapt the scroll length where the last row of the `UICollectionView` always appears above the floating button?

Haven't found anything to reference and am admittedly lost on implementation. Hope for any thoughts..

Below is the desired functionality:

[image]

Comment: If I read things correctly, this button **is not* part of the collection view in terms of view hierarchy. So the actual question - which is not really part of anything in your's - is to (a) keep the position of the button while (b) scrolling through the collection view and (c) adjust the button position based on something (possibly the last row of the collection view)? You've asked a pretty good question. It's just vague (to me) on this.

Comment: Tou should modify the bottom `contentInset` to the value of the buttons height (and possibly some margins).

Comment: Can you add a quick drawing or mock of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it so that your `UICollectionView` scrolls above your button by setting a `contentInset` to account for the height of your button (plus the buffer above and below the button. That could look something like this:

```
collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: button.bounds.size.height + buffer, right: 0)
```

"buffer" is a placeholder for whatever you want to add to account for the space above and below the button.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you could do something like that:

```
yourButton.zPosition = 100
```

And your button should appear above your collection view.